# Am I overusing cross apply to create new columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, cross-apply

I am using t-sql on various sql server versions.

From the moment I learned about cross apply, I have been using it quite frequently. The specific kind of use I want to discuss is the use of one

```
cross apply (select really_long_statement where correlated_join_condition) as tablename(fieldname)
```

statement. I am using this to make code clearer, as I have read here on the "Introduce new columns!" section:
[http://bradsruminations.blogspot.gr/2011/04/t-sql-tuesday-017-it-slices-it-dices-it.html](http://Brad%20Schulz's%20cross%20apply%20blog%20post)

It is obvious to me that the exact same function of the statement I mentioned earlied can be achieved by this:

```
inner join (select correlated_join_condition_fields,really_long_statement) as tablename(fieldname) on correlated_join_condition
```

Being a little lazy, initially I would prefer the first solution, because i do not have to type twice the join condition fields.
Then I thought, cross apply is less known and used from inner join, so maybe it would be a good idea to stick to inner join for the sake of writing easier to maintain code.
But then, I peeked the query plan for an instance of those two scenarios, and noticed the cross apply was actually faster!! I did not expect this; from all the posts I've read about plans, it seems that most of the time, when two queries do the same thing and are not hugely different, the plan analyzer will figure this and make the same plan.

I am not able to upload the plans at the time of writing this, but I will be able to in a couple of days.

So, the question is, why does cross apply seem faster? Is it because it does not have to make the join condition fields available?

Plus any opinions about the balance of performance/easy to read code/short to write code would be welcome.

Comment: You have to analyze query plans. It depends on indexes and statistics.

Comment: I'd love to answer this but the question is rather vague and too broad for this forum.  The apply operator is a game changer and brilliant for such things s a "top n" and it is also great for providing aliases that can be used in the reminder of the from clause and where clause etc.